# Can STRING_AGG be used multiple times with different delimiters?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I was doing some string aggregation and noticed what looked like a bug to me. `STRING_AGG` was used twice in the same query with different separator arguments. However, both produced the same results (the "first" separator is used in both cases). It seems to happen only in *some* circumstances. Is this a bug or is this documented behavior?

First, the setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Data
  ([Group] INT
 , Member  CHAR(1));

INSERT INTO #Data
VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')
     , (2, 'c'), (2, 'd');
```

From a table vs. `VALUES` constructor. Without `WITHIN GROUP` `ORDER BY`, everything is fine. With it, the bug appears

```sql
SELECT Commas = STRING_AGG(Member, ', ') --WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Member)
     , Colons = STRING_AGG(Member, '::') --WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Member)
FROM #Data;

SELECT Commas = STRING_AGG(Member, ', ') --WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Member)
     , Colons = STRING_AGG(Member, '::') --WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY Member)
FROM (VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')
           , (2, 'c'), (2, 'd')) [v] ([Group], Member);
```

Adding in a `GROUP BY` adds a sort and the error is there for both cases now:

```sql
SELECT [Group]
     , Commas = STRING_AGG(Member, ', ')
     , Colons = STRING_AGG(Member, '::')
FROM #Data
GROUP BY [Group];

SELECT [Group]
     , Commas = STRING_AGG(Member, ', ')
     , Colons = STRING_AGG(Member, '::')
FROM (VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')
           , (2, 'c'), (2, 'd')) [v] ([Group], Member)
GROUP BY [Group];
```

Add it's definitely broken... like deep down. Combine both expressions in a `HAVING` and you get nothing back. Use either one alone, and you get data.

```sql
SELECT [Group]
     , Colons = STRING_AGG(Member, '::')
     , Commas = STRING_AGG(Member, ', ')
FROM #Data
GROUP BY [Group]
HAVING STRING_AGG(Member, ', ') LIKE '%, %'
   AND STRING_AGG(Member, '::') LIKE '%::%';
```

Switching the order of the columns switches the separator used.

I used these trace flags for investigating, but I can't find anything about "optimizing" away the second aggregate.

```sql
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604 -- Output info to client
      , QUERYTRACEON 8619 -- Show applied optimization rules
      , QUERYTRACEON 8606 -- Show logical query trees
      , QUERYTRACEON 8607 -- Show physical query tree
      , RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: *Can STRING_AGG be used multiple times with different delimiters?* Of course. Your expressions are independent. *However* It seems 2017 have some problems with this function. Look [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=be3085c11e94da5045ccf8714f8637d9) - on 2019 everything works correct, but try to alter server version. And [fiddle2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63c2c/1) (2017 only). And the problem of "'Multiple ordered aggregate functions in the same scope have mutually incompatible orderings.'" can be found in different bugreports (including cases with implicit sorting).

Comment: "2017 has some problems with this function." Yes. It's broken. I did search the SQL Server UserVoice. [This has been reported before.](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/35803012)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52533487/string-agg-not-behaving-as-expected/52534215#52534215) indicates that it is fixed in CU17 but I just tested that and found it negative (and there is no indication that the fix was intended to be backported [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/368212e1-0762-47d7-861d-1b7abb4320cb/bug-in-stringagg-delimiters-azure-sql-database-and-sql-server-2017?forum=ssdsgetstarted#71b0a823-5aee-4e4e-b947-4e1e0c222863)).

I tried

```
SELECT [Group]
     , Commas = STRING_AGG(Member, ', ')
     , Colons = STRING_AGG(Member, '::')
FROM (VALUES (1, 'a'), (1, 'b')
           , (2, 'c'), (2, 'd')) [v] ([Group], Member)
GROUP BY [Group]
OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 3604 -- Output info to client
      , QUERYTRACEON 8607 -- Optimization output tree, before post-optimization rewrite phase.
      , QUERYTRACEON 7352 -- The final query tree after Post-optimization re-write.
      , RECOMPILE);
;
```

In 2017 CU17. This gives plan

[image]

On 2019 there is no compute scalar and the Stream Aggregate has defined values

```
[Expr1010] = Scalar Operator(STRING_AGG([Union1009],', ')), 
[Expr1011] = Scalar Operator(STRING_AGG([Union1009],'::'))
```

On 2017 the Stream Aggregate has defined value

```
[Expr1010] = Scalar Operator(STRING_AGG([Union1009],', '))
```

And there is an additional Compute Scalar with expression

```
[Expr1011] = Scalar Operator([Expr1010])
```

The output of trace flag `8607`is the same on 2017 and 2019 but `7352` differs so I assume this is a faulty post optimisation rewrite.

As a workaround you can change the expression to do a no-op as below to prevent this faulty optimisation.

```
SELECT [Group]
     , Commas = STRING_AGG(Member, ', ')
     , Colons = STRING_AGG('' + Member, '::')
```