# JSON - How do I get JSON Child Array into one column - OPENJSON in Synapse

Tags: t-sql, json

I've broken this down with executable code. I need to get the lang and value columns into a single record. Any ideas on how to go about this:

```
DECLARE
@JSONMain NVARCHAR(1000)

SET @JSONMain = N'{ "problemtype_data": [
        {
            "description": [
                {
                    "lang": "en",
                    "value": "CWE-200"
                },
                {
                    "lang": "en",
                    "value": "NVD-CWE-noinfo"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'

SELECT  Problem.ProblemType, Problem.ProblemTypeLang
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONMain, '$.problemtype_data')
WITH (
    PrblmTypeJSON NVARCHAR(max) '$.description' as JSON
) ProblemType
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(ProblemType.PrblmTypeJSON, '$')
WITH (
    ProblemType NVARCHAR(15) '$.value',
    ProblemTypeLang NVARCHAR(5) '$.lang'
) Problem
```

The executed code produces:
[image]

I would like to see it like this:
**ProblemType**:                                  **ProblemTypeLang**:

CWE-200, NVD-CWE-noinfo            en,en

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the values using `STRING_AGG` inside an `APPLY`. If you want to get the values in the order they were in the array, you need another `OPENJSON` without a schema, in order to get the index.

```sql
SELECT
  p.ProblemType, p.ProblemTypeLang
FROM OPENJSON(@JSONMain, '$.problemtype_data')
  WITH (
    description nvarchar(max) AS JSON
  ) ProblemType
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT
      ProblemType = STRING_AGG(Problem.lang, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.[key]),
      ProblemTypeLang = STRING_AGG(Problem.value, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY v.[key])
    FROM OPENJSON(ProblemType.description) array
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(array.value)
      WITH (
        value nvarchar(15),
        lang nvarchar(5)
      ) Problem
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(array.[key] AS int)) v([key])
) p;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=caf3644546fa2bb6b5f0125e14e6ea9e)

> The extra `CROSS APPLY` to convert the index was due to [this bug in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/257819/220697) which was appearing, [see fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6dec88c777149aa9c203dd11a8647f49).